Time-sensitive network for connected applications using OPC UA
I have been developing an application that would benefit from faster, more reliable, and ideally synchronized, communication. This led me to look at whether we could implement the App using the open-source provided by OPC Foundation and open62541 Foundation. It appears we can, however, there appear to be some specific hardware requirements (bridges, etc.) that are not available by default when communicating across the internet. Is that correct? Or does as standard fast domestic fibre connection do what we need?
Also, I seems like the internet already provides Precision Time Protocol PTP communications for audio visual applications under 802.1Qav. This may in fact be a good starting point for us, so can someone explain if would be feasible to use OPC UA / open62541 with 802.1Qav. And if your wondering - I am Systems Engineer not Networking engineer!

PTP is a time synchronization protocol, roughly a successor to NTP. It is not a communications protocol. 802.1Qav is specifically for local area networks. You will not get guaranteed reliability on internet connections as there are too many components outside of your control. Faster may also not be possible with latency between sites dependent on the speed of light.

As doneal24 says, PTP is a clock synchronization, not a streaming protocol.  PTP (IEEE 1588-2002 and -2008) is also designed for local networks with reliable clocking, not for use over the internet; because you can't PTP-sync across multiple network boundaries without a PTP boundary clock. So, if you need timing precision better than what you can achieve with NTP, you'll have to do things like having GPS-derived clocks on both local networks (between which the internet lies). Of course, you can't make any hard real time constraints on packet transport through the internet at all, so the

question becomes what you really hope to achieve there – simple example: you hit a button in factory A and want to guarantee that exactly 20 ms later, some machine stops in factory B, connected through the internet. No matter how much soft- and hardware you layer on top, this is impossible, because you can't guarantee that packets going through the internet won't take longer than 20 ms – it's not a connection-oriented means of communication, and it has random packet delivery times and orderings.

Same as for PTP applies to TSN/IEEE 802.11Qav. It needs specific hardware bridges at the edges of network segments. So, maybe I'm just misunderstanding your requirement that "the internet provides" implies you want to use the internet?
